# 2D Linked List with multiple pointers C

Tags: c, list, pointers, 2d

I do have 2 structures here.
main linked list is the word.
each node of the word list do have a meaning

```
typedef struct node{
  char word[20];
  struct node2 *meaning;
  struct node *next;
}word;

typedef struct node2{
  char meaning[100];
  struct node2 *next;
}means;
```

My problem now is I can't add multiple meanings. I can just add 1 meaning and whenever i try to add, it overwrites the previous meaning instead., how can i do this? this is how i add meaning

```
word *tmp2=(*head);
means *tmp3;
tmp3=(means *)malloc(sizeof(means));
if(tmp2==NULL){
  printf("\n**List still empty, add a word**\n");
  return;
}
do{
  if(strcmp(tmp2->word,ins)==0){
    tmp2->meaning=tmp3;
    strcpy(tmp3->meaning,mea);
    tmp3->next=NULL;
    printf("\n**You have successfully added a meaning**\n");
    return;
  }
  tmp2=tmp2->next;
}while(tmp2!=NULL);
printf("\n**Word is not on the list, cannot add meaning**\n");
return;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
tmp2->meaning=tmp3;
strcpy(tmp3->meaning,mea);
tmp3->next=NULL;
```

You overwrite the meaning in the word element of your struct, and set its next to NULL, so you lose the previous tmp2->meaning forever.

You could easily add it on top of the previous meanings :

```
tmp3->next = tmp2->meaning;
strcpy(tmp3->meaning, mea);
tmp2->meaning = tmp3;
```

If you want to display the meanings :

```
void display_meanings_of(word *w)
{
  means *m;

  m = w->meaning;
  if (m)
    printf("Meanings of the word %s:\n", w->word);
  else
    printf("The word %s has no meaning.\n", w->word);
  while (m)
  {
    printf(" - %s\n", m->meaning);
    m = m->next;
  }
}
```

Comment: @eregith
how can i view those meanings? i used this snippet:
but it only prints the 2 last meanings... 
`code`
do{
   printf("\n-%s\n",tmp->meaning->meaning);
   tmp->meaning=tmp->meaning->next;
}while(tmp->meaning!=NULL);
`code`

Comment: This will also replace the first of the list inside tmp. I'm editing my answer to tell you

Comment: @eregith, i've applied the changes, it does only print the 1st and last meaning..

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
tmp2->meaning=tmp3;
strcpy(tmp3->meaning,mea);
tmp3->next=NULL;
```

The first line just overwrite the existing pointer, and you set the `next` pointer to `NULL` in the last line.

Instead you need to *link* the new meaning into the list. This is done by setting `tmp2->meaning` to `NULL` when creating the `word` pointer, and use something like

```
tmp3->next = tmp2->meaning;
tmp2->meaning = tmp3;

strcpy(tmp3->meaning, mea);
```

Now `tmp3` will always be put at the head of the list, and make `tmp3->next` point to the previous head, or `NULL` if there were no previous head.

**Edit:** Function to view meanings:

```
void show_meanings(word *w)
{
    int i;
    means *m;
    for (m = w->meaning, i = 1; m != NULL; m = m->next, i++)
        printf("Meaning %d: %s\n", i, m->meaning);
}
```

Comment: how can i view those meanings? i used this snippet:
but it only prints the 2 last meanings... 
`code`
do{
   printf("\n-%s\n",tmp->meaning->meaning);
   tmp->meaning=tmp->meaning->next;
}while(tmp->meaning!=NULL);
`code`

Comment: @vaizaren And you added more than two meanings? In that case something else is wrong.

Comment: @joachin pileborg, yes, i've added more than two meanings... only two meanings are being viewed.. i think there is some mistake in adding the meaning..

Comment: @vaizaren Provide a [Short Self Contained Compilable Example](http://www.sscce.org)

Answer (score 0):

What are the parameters for this function you are writing? 
What is (*head)? what is "ins"? what is "mea""?

I think checking and returning after malloc without free-ing up the memory is not a good idea. If you keep adding a meaning into an empty list, the heap will eventually run out of memory.

```
word *tmp2=(*head);
means *tmp3;
tmp3=(means *)malloc(sizeof(means));
if(tmp2==NULL){
  printf("\n**List still empty, add a word**\n");
  return;
}
```

Suggested:

```
word *tmp2=(*head);
means *tmp3;
if(tmp2==NULL){
  printf("\n**List still empty, add a word**\n");
  return;
}
// if tmp2 is not null then we malloc
tmp3=(means *)malloc(sizeof(means));
```